# upload json config file with azure functions?

Tags: azure, azure-functions

I have Azure functions with configs (database connection strings, active directory, etc) set up for dev and live environments, right now I have everything in a class and I comment in/out the bits I'm using or not using.

Is there a way to upload a json file with the azure functions that will guide its config?

Answer (score 2):

You mention "upload a json file" so I'm assuming that you're referring to some sort of release management activity. My suggestion is to simply use the built in AppSettings. Your use case is essentially what they are built for. Generally speaking if you store your settings within the appsettings of a function app and you have separate environments for your functions (dev & live) then you don't need to manage a separate json configuration file. The environment owns the configuration and your code will get the settings from the current environment.

If you have a more complex deployment and configuration management scenario I would consider using a release management tool such as VSTS to manage those configuration settings as part of the release pipeline so each environment has the correct settings at deployment time. Most CI\CD tools have functionality to update json configuration and\or update Azure App configuration directly.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. You need to add connection strings as Application Settings. [Azure Functions Core Tools](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-run-local) uses [local.settings.json file](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-run-local#local-settings-file) to read your connection strings when running locally and these settings are not pushed to Azure when published.